# Naming convention of .unl files

Tags: export, informix

I would like to understand which is the rule that is applied for the naming convention of the `.unl` files generated once I use `dbexport` on my Informix database.

I understand that:

  + Each file refers to a different table

  + Each file uses 5 letters and 5 numbers (example:
  `tbabc01234.unl`
  , if table name is
  `tbabcdef`
  ).

  + The 5 letters are the first 5 letters of the table name.

  + If the table name has less than 5 letters, it completes it with underscores (example:
  `tby__01234.unl`
  , if table name is
  `tby`
  )

I would like to understand what is the meaning of the 5 numbers. Is there a way to guarantee that the list is alphabetically generated?

Comment: Historically, there were 7 letters and 3 digits, but bigger databases etc triggered a change.  If there is a need for more than 5 digits, more than 5 will be used, and I think the number of letters goes down to match.  It takes a while to create (and drop) 99,999 tables so it is seldom a problem.  The rules on Windows with the legacy of 8.3 file names are probably more stringent.

Comment: What do you mean by 'alphabetically generated'?

Comment: Ricardo answered my questions! But, by 'alphabetically generated' I meant if the numbers (the table ids) were generated in a sequential order according to the names of the tables. That's not true, because the numbers are the table ids, as Ricardo answered.

Comment: In Informix-SE 4.10.DD6, the last MS-DOS version of the standard engine, when a table is created, the first 5 letters of the table name and a 3 digit sequence number, begining with 102, make up the name for the .DAT and .IDX filenames in the dbs directory. If the table name is less than 5 characters, then the filenames are padded with underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5 digits number used on the unload file is the `tabid` of the table.

I don't believe there is a way to guarantee that the list is alphabetically generated.

[The dbexport and dbimport utilities](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.mig.doc/ids_mig_113.htm?lang=en)

To get the `tabid` of a table query the [systables](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_072.htm?lang=en) system catalog table:

```
SELECT  tabname, tabid
FROM    systables
WHERE   tabname = '<TABNAME>';
```

For a given list:

```
SELECT  tabname, tabid
FROM    systables
WHERE   tabname IN (
            '<TABNAME1>',
            '<TABNAME2>',
            '<TABNAME3>',
            ...
        )
ORDER BY tabid;
```

For all user tables:

```
SELECT  tabname, tabid
FROM    systables
WHERE   tabid > 99 
        AND tabtype = 'T'
ORDER BY tabid;
```

Needless to say you can reverse search by `tabid`:

```
SELECT  tabname, tabid
FROM    systables
WHERE   tabid = '<TABNAME>';

SELECT  tabname, tabid
FROM    systables
WHERE   tabid IN (
            101,
            102,
            103,
            ...
        )
ORDER BY tabid;
```

One way of mapping is:

```
SELECT  tabname, 
        tabid,
        RPAD(SUBSTR(tabname,0, 5), 5, '_')||tabid||'.unl' AS unl_file, 
FROM    systables
WHERE   tabid > 99 
        AND tabtype = 'T'
ORDER BY tabid;
```

For the question if this is a good approach, it depends on some questions:

- How many tables the source database has?
- How many tables you intend to migrate?
- The process should account for relations between tables and data (PK/FK/Triggers/...).
- Remember the storage clause mentions the dbspaces when using the `ss` option.
- ...

For example, if you have a database with 1000 tables and just want 10, then it is easier to extract the schema from [dbschema](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.mig.doc/ids_mig_154.htm?lang=en) and then perform an [unload](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1248.htm?lang=en) of the data.

Here is a link of the list of [Data migration utilities](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.mig.doc/ids_mig_246.htm?lang=en) that comes with the engine.

Comment: Thank you, Ricardo! Do you know if there is a way to map these files? I need to import (dbload) some specific tables from development to production database. I think I will use dbexport and than I would like to dbload just the specific .unl of the tables I need. Do you believe this is a good approach? Thank you very much